# Pandas - How to create new columns derived from the values in two consecutive rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe -

```
ID    Name   Distance   Time   Base    Height
1     A      10         2      12      2
2     A      20         4      14      3
3     B      30         6      16      4
4     B      40         8      18      5
5     C      50         10     20      6   
6     C      60         12     22      8
```

I want to create new columns `Speed, Tarea, Speed_ratio, Tarea_ratio` whose values are derived from the values in rows with Names `A,B,C` as follows -

```
ID    Name   Distance   Time   Base    Height   Speed    Tarea    Speed_ratio   Tarea_ratio
1     A      10         2      12      2        5        12       1             0.5714
2     A      20         4      14      3        5        21       NA            NA   
3     B      30         6      16      4        5        32       1             0.7111 
4     B      40         8      18      5        5        45       NA            NA
5     C      50         10     20      6        5        60       1             0.6818    
6     C      60         12     22      8        5        88       NA            NA
```

Can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic for calculating `Tarea`, `Tarea_ratio` and `Speed_ratio`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal The author definitely could have been more explicit, but from context, it looks like the `Tarea` is the "triangular area" (`Base * Height / 2`) and the ratios are taken by grouping the rows by `Name` and dividing the first elements of the resulting pairs by the second.

Comment: @ErickShepherd Yes, I think I got it after sometime. Have answered accordingly. Please have a look.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Likewise. It looks like we came to pretty similar solutions, but I like your answer. I wasn't able to figure out the trick for doing it with a `groupby` until I saw your answer, so I had improvised. The use of `shift` was a neat idea: I didn't even know that was a method for `groupby` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the below:

```
In [431]: df['Speed'] = df.Distance.div(df.Time)
In [433]: df['Tarea'] = df.Base.mul(df.Height)/2

In [447]: df['Speed_ratio'] = df.Speed / df.groupby('Name').Speed.shift(-1)
    
In [450]: df['Tarea_ratio'] = df.Tarea / df.groupby('Name').Tarea.shift(-1)

In [451]: df
Out[451]: 
   ID Name  Distance  Time  Base  Height  Speed  Tarea  Speed_ratio  Tarea_ratio
0   1    A        10     2    12       2    5.0   12.0          1.0     0.571429
1   2    A        20     4    14       3    5.0   21.0          NaN          NaN
2   3    B        30     6    16       4    5.0   32.0          1.0     0.711111
3   4    B        40     8    18       5    5.0   45.0          NaN          NaN
4   5    C        50    10    20       6    5.0   60.0          1.0     0.681818
5   6    C        60    12    22       8    5.0   88.0          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Hi - Is it possible to not show "NaN"'s in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use operators between columns:

```
df["Speed"]=5
df["Tarea"]=df["Base"]*df["Height"]/2 # that column will have float values, if you want to have integer values, use astype() method.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign new columns by using `df[key] = value`, as you would for a native `dict` object. For your particular case, the following would work:

```
df["Speed"]       = df["Distance"] / df["Time"]
df["Tarea"]       = df["Base"] * df["Height"] / 2
df["Speed_ratio"] = df["Speed"].iloc[::2] / df["Speed"].iloc[1::2].values
df["Tarea_ratio"] = df["Tarea"].iloc[::2] / df["Tarea"].iloc[1::2].values
```

Which gives the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
ID  Name  Distance  Time  Base  Height  Speed  Tarea  Speed_ratio  Tarea_ratio
 1     A        10     2    12       2    5.0   12.0          1.0     0.571429
 2     A        20     4    14       3    5.0   21.0          NaN          NaN
 3     B        30     6    16       4    5.0   32.0          1.0     0.711111
 4     B        40     8    18       5    5.0   45.0          NaN          NaN
 5     C        50    10    20       6    5.0   60.0          1.0     0.681818
 6     C        60    12    22       8    5.0   88.0          NaN          NaN
```